# Setting an SPF record for all subdomains of my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

Is this possible? Like a wildcard TXT record of some sort?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to define a wildcard TXT record.

<strike>Notice that you should define both a TXT RR and a SPF RR.</strike>
**Update:** This answer was originally made in 2011. At the time SPF RR was a thing. However, according to [RFC7208](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7208#section-3.1) the use of SPF RR has been discontinued and SPF content should only be published in TXT records.

**Example**
In my home I run a local DNS server with the .fbh domain extension, I have created this record:

```
*.email         IN  TXT "v=spf1 mx -all exp=bad.example.com"
```

And this gives me the same response for all queries to *.email.fbh:

```
$ dig +short TXT test.email.fbh
"v=spf1 mx -all exp=bad.example.com"

$ dig +short TXT smth.email.fbh
"v=spf1 mx -all exp=bad.example.com"
```

Comment: I was under the impression that SPF RRs were not implemented in the standard yet.

Comment: For reference: http://rfc.frands.net/rfc4408.txt  see 3.1.1

Comment: What is "RR"? thanks

Comment: Old, but for posterity... It means resource record. SPF resource records are now obsolete; just a TXT record will do.

Answer (score 9):

You can, however, include a central spf record in the invidual subdomain spf records.

Each individual spf records for the subdomains could look like this:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.domain.tld ~all
```

And then add a TXT record for _spf.domain.tld with the actual spf values:

```
v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4/30 200.298.100.1/24 ~all
```

This way, you only need to maintain _spf.domain.tld, and not the records for the individual subdomains

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to seting up spf macros now a days. which is mostly used for

> SPF macros are a feature of the SPF specification which allow for the
> creation of dynamic SPF policies. They allow for variables to be
> included within a policy, which are then evaluated by the receiving
> MTA and 'filled in' using data from the email being processed, such as
> the sender address or source IP address.

[you can set macros like this also](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4408#section-8)